# CouchDB Search and Replace

Tags: couchdb, database, nosql

I have a couchDB database, in my documents I have a series of strings (stored as JSON objects) unfortunately during the submission the strings were escaped so that "\n" is inserted as "\\n" into the database.

Is it possible to run a search and replace operation to reverse this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't perform a "search and replace" like you are probably thinking. Your best bet is to use the [bulk document API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html?highlight=bulk#post--db-_bulk_docs) to write changes to multiple documents simultaneously.

You'll need some sort of script to query all docs (or you could write a view to find those that need to be updated) and then you'll submit your changes via the bulk docs API.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Dominic, I will take a look